# Are chat rooms hard-deleted?

Tags: support, chat, deleted-room

There have been a few chat rooms I've found before that later got deleted due to inactivity and not being considered worth keeping. Now I want to see the full transcript of one of those rooms, but it's been deleted, and I'm not sure if there's any way to find it again.

Are chat rooms hard-deleted like user profiles are, or is there some way to see the content of a deleted chat room?

Comment: There's at least one deleted room I'm able to see due to having more than 10k rep on the entire network. Unsure if this applies to all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. The transcripts are visible for users **with 10k reputation networkwide**. If some specific messages are deleted, there is no way to look at them unless you're an Room Owner or a moderator. These users with 10k rep networkwide can also handle spam/offensive flags raised.

[image: spam/offensive flags shown to 10k users networkwide]

The reputation earned varies for three chat servers. To see deleted rooms in chat.meta.stackexchange server, you should earn 10k on Meta Stack Exchange. Reputation on Stack Overflow and other sites do not count. Same with stack Overflow. But your reputation on SO and MSE will count towards your network wide 10k rep on Chat.stackexchange server.

To look at frozen and deleted rooms, select show frozen/deleted rooms

[image: Image showing options to show frozen rooms]

Here's an image how they look after selecting show frozen/deleted rooms.

[image: Image showing hidden and deleted rooms]

The faded dark rooms are Frozen rooms. The ones which are pale and white are deleted rooms either by a moderator or due to inactivity.

Frozen rooms have a message "This room is frozen; new messages cannot be added." but deleted rooms do not have this message.

Comment: Rooms which a moderator decided to privatize before deleting are not visible to <10k users.